# How to avoid If and else in spread operator Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JS. I am trying to simplify my code but its throwing me an syntax error. Is there any way I can avoid multiple codes like not using If and else statement. Below is the code I posted for reference.

the only difference is item.href.replace statement will have "?".

```js
(() => {
    const test = 'x=abc';

    if (location.search == "") {
        [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
            .filter(link => link.href.includes(test))
            .forEach(item => (item.href = item.href.replace(`${test}`, location.search)));
    } else {
        [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
            .filter(link => link.href.includes(test))
            .forEach(item => (item.href = item.href.replace(`?${test}`, location.search)));
    }
})();
```

Comment: Is that `?` supposed to be inside the string?

Comment: You can use the contains selector instead of filter: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

Comment: My bad its supposed to be inside the string

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: just use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to append ? depending on if search is an empty string

Answer (score 3):

You can simply assign the string you want before the operation.

```js
const test = 'x=abc';
let search = (location.search == "") ? test : `?${test}`;

[...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
    .filter(link => link.href.includes(test))
    .forEach(item => (item.href = item.href.replace(search, location.search)));
```

Comment: Thats nice. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

Well, the actual clean solution would be:

```
  [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]
        .filter(link => link.href.includes(test))
        .forEach(link => link.search = link.search.replace(test, location.search));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can approach this refactoring through 3 steps:

1. Move the `document.querySelectorAll('a')` to the top
2. Filter the resulting `<a>` tags that match our criteria through our selector through the [`~=` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
3. Return the results in our `function`

The resulting code might look something like this:

```js
const replaceQueryParams = function(test) {
  const matchingLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll(`a[href~="${test}"]`)];
  return matchingLinks.map((link) => link.href = link.href.replace(`?${test}`, window.location.search));
};
```

We can then use the `replaceQueryParams` function like so:

```js
const replacedLinkStrings = replaceQueryParams("my-test-string");
if (replacedLinkStrings.length > 0) {
  console.log("Do something here");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the selector you want, and you can just remove the spread and use forEach